# angular implement my own compoment with ngModel

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, ngmodel

I have got the following HTML and want to have `myModel` synchronised whenever either `input` or `my-component` changes.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myModel" />
<my-component [(ngModel)]="myMdoel></my-component>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <input type="text" name="item{{item.name}}" [(ngModel)]="item.name" />
    <my-component [(model)]="item.name" [datasource]="source"></my-component>
</div>
```

My Component

```
<button type="button" *ngFor="let s of datasource" (click)="selectItem(s)">{{s}}</button>

export class MyComponent ... {
    _model: any;

    @Input()
    get model(): any {
        return this._model;
    }

    @Input()
    set model(value: any) {
        this._model = vaue;
    }

    @Output() modelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    @Input() datasource: any[];

    ...

    selectItem(item: any): void {
        this._model = item;
        this.modelChange.emit(this._model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share my-component code

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a variable on your component and use @Input event emitter as follows

```
<my-component [myModelVar]="myMdoel></my-component>
```

and in your my-componnet.ts

```
@input myModelVar;
```

here **`myModelVar`** will have the changes when you update myModel on your parent component

Comment: What if I change the value in `my-component`? Will the new value reflect in the `input`?

Comment: you need to implement @output event emitter and pass the value to parent

Comment: but for every different parent, it seems that i have to implement something to receive that emission from `my-component`?

Comment: yes otherwise you can use object and make it on one go